# SQL perform a Calculation inside a GROUP BY

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

Here is my code:

```
$query = DB::table('notification');
        $query->leftJoin('rule', 'notification.rule_id', '=', 'rule.rule_id');
        $query->leftJoin('agent', 'notification.agent_id', '=', 'agent.agent_id')
                    ->leftJoin('department', 'agent.department_id', '=', 'department.department_id')
                    ->select(
                        DB::raw("coalesce(department.name, '$this->defaultDepartment') as tag"),
                        DB::raw('count(*) as count'),
                        //DB::raw('rule.quotient * count') as score
                        )
                    ->groupBy('tag')
                    ->orderBy('count', 'desc');
```

I want to calculate the score for each department: which is
the sum of all risk scores of rules by agents in the department (grouped by departments).

FYI to calculate a single agent score it is (rule.quotient * count of rule) ie the number the rule appears.

I would provide a db structure, but I think the query clears that.

How do I go about it?

Regards

Comment: Can I see the full query string this php outputs please.

Comment: @Jeff For now this is what I have:
"select coalesce(department.name, 'None') as tag, count(*) as count, (SELECT SUM( from "notification" left join "rule" on "notification"."rule_id" = "rule"."rule_id" left join "agent" on "notification"."agent_id" = "agent"."agent_id" left join "department" on "agent"."department_id" = "department"."department_id" where "notification"."timestamp" between ? and ? group by "tag" order by "count" desc"

Comment: and does that run? - I ask because it doesn't look like it would - specifically around this piece here: (SELECT SUM( from "notification" left join "rule" ...

Comment: What is "rule.quotient * count of rule"? Rule has properties quotient and count? Or every rule has a quotient that affects it's weight. I have 3 rules with quotients 1, 2 and 3 - what's my score?

Comment: @RobertGoldman Rule has property rule.quotient and count is the number of time that rule is broken by an agent

Comment: @Jeff Sorry for that, that select should not be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query is correct, the laravel query would look like below:

```
$query = DB::table('notification');
        $query->leftJoin('rule', 'notification.rule_id', '=', 'rule.rule_id');
        $query->leftJoin('agent', 'notification.agent_id', '=', 'agent.agent_id')
                    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(Select coalesce(department.name, '$this->defaultDepartment') as tag, count(*) as count from department)as department'),function($join){
                            $join->on('agent.department_id', '=', 'department.department_id')
                        ;})
                    ->groupBy('tag')
                    ->orderBy('count', 'desc');
```

### Update:

```
$query = DB::table('notification');        
$query->leftJoin('agent', 'notification.agent_id', '=', 'agent.agent_id')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(Select coalesce(department.name, '$this->defaultDepartment') as tag, count(*) as count from department)as department'),function($join){
                    $join->on('agent.department_id', '=', 'department.department_id');
                ;})
$query->leftJoin(DB::raw('(Select (quotient * department.count) as score from rule) as rule'),function ($join){
                $join->on('rule', 'notification.rule_id', '=', 'rule.rule_id');
            });
        ->groupBy('tag')
        ->orderBy('count', 'desc');
```

Comment: I though it is commented

Comment: I actually want to calculate score which is the sum risk score by agents in the department. risk score is quotient * the number of times the rule appears

Comment: Check the update.. It is supposed to work.. but I don't have my laravel box with me right now to test

Comment: count should come from rules rather than from departments

Comment: Could you please post your DB schema ?